# Map data types to Series or lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, mapping

I am trying to map a dict that contains the data type of each column of a DataFrame, I am trying something like this:

```
data_types = {"AR3": float, 
             "AR66": float, 
             "AR10": str, 
             "AR69": str, 
             "AR61": float, 
             "AR106": float, 
             "AR109": float, 
             "AR107": str,
             "AR119": float,
             "AR1": float}


>>> df.dtypes
AR3               int64
AR55     datetime64[ns]
AR66            float64
AR10             object
AR69              int64
AR61              int64
AR106            object
AR109           float64
AR107             int64
AR119           float64
AR1              object
AR113    datetime64[ns]

######################
# What I am trying/getting:
######################

>>> df.dtypes.map(data_types)

AR3      NaN
AR55     NaN
AR66     NaN
AR10     NaN
AR69     NaN
AR61     NaN
AR106    NaN
AR109    NaN
AR107    NaN
AR119    NaN
AR1      NaN
AR113    NaN
```

Ideally I would also like to incorporate the `datetime` objects in my mapping, but I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```py
data_types = {
    'AR3': float,
    'AR55': 'datetime64[ns]'
    'AR66': float,
    'AR10': str,
    'AR69': str,
    'AR61': float,
    'AR106': float,
    'AR109': float,
    'AR107': str,
    'AR119': float,
    'AR1': float,
    'AR113': 'datetime64[ns]'
}

for k, v in data_types.items():
    df[k] = df[k].astype(v)
```

Comment: Super. :) If my answer was helpful, don't forget [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it.